# Stuck with code concatenation + row_number SQL code

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is what my data looks like :

```
id  type    row_number
---------------------------
1a  a         1
1a  a         2
1a  b         3
1a  b         4
1a  c         5
1a  b         6
2a  b         1
2a  b         2
2a  c         3
2a  a         4
2a  c
```

and I want the new variable new_type as mentioned below,

```
id  new_type    
-------------
1a  a_b_c   
2a  b_c_a
```

For example: ID = 1a, times purchased = 1 then new_type = type and it will add another type like concat (times purchased does not matter for next type).

Tried this code "

```
select id,
stuff((case when t.seqnum = '1' then '_' + type else '' end) +
              (case when t.seqnum = '2' then '_' + type else '' end) +
              (case when t.seqnum = '3' then '_' + type else '' end),
              1, 1, '') as new_type
from (select t.id, t.type , min(t.rowno) as min_tp, row_number() over (partition by t.id order by min(t.rowno)) as seqnum
      from try2 as t
      group by t.id, t.type 
     ) t
group by id;
```

but this is giving me an error:

> SQL Error [8120] [S0001]: Column 't.seqnum' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: Why do you need an urgent response?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1787.0 (X64)

Comment: If it's so urgent why haven't you tried to solve the problem *yourself* first? You'd get a far quicker resolution then, instead of asking (begging) us to do *your* work for you for **free**.

Comment: I tried, but could not achieve it.

Comment: *"I tried, but could not achieve it."* then show us that attempt in your question.

Comment: On a separate note, if you are using unsupported technology (which SQl Server 2008 is) you should really be tagging the version in your question. SQL Server 2008 is now completely unsupported, and ideally you should be looking at upgrade paths as soon as you can.

Comment: You didn't try that code; that's Gordon's solution (even if it doesn't work). What was ***your*** attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have just a few types, you can do:

```
select id,
       stuff( max(case when seqnum = 1 then '_' + type else '' end) +
              max(case when seqnum = 2 then '_' + type else '' end) +
              max(case when seqnum = 3 then '_' + type else '' end),
              1, 1, ''
            ) as new_type
from (select t.id, t.type, min(t.times_purchased) as min_tp,
             row_number() over (partition by t.id order by min(t.times_purchased)) as seqnum
      from t
      group by t.id, t.type
     ) t
group by id;
```

You will need a separate `case` for each type.

Note that it is tempting to use `string_agg()` here, but there is no way to control the ordering of the resulting string.

Comment: *"Note that it is tempting to use string_agg() here, but there is no way to control the ordering of the resulting string."* This isn't true. If you use the `WITHIN GROUP` clause you can provide an `ORDER BY` clause. Note the *<order_clause>* section in the [Arguments](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments) documentation. The point, however, is moot as it turns out the OP is using an unsupported version of SQL Server (2008), and not the latest current release version (2017); which the only one that supports `STRING_AGG`.

Comment: Of course they are using 2008 so string_agg isn't an option, plus they have nothing in their data to use a sorting column (maybe times_purchased).

Comment: I am getting an error: SQL Error [8120] [S0001]: Column 't.seqnum' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

This works on **a few** of assumptions; if my *assumptions* are wrong then it's up to you to fix them, as we are still awaiting your attempts, etc.

The fact that you are using an unsupported version of SQL Server doesn't make this as easy either, but anyway, this *appears* to work:

```
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('1a','a',1),
                ('1a','a',2),
                ('1a','b',3),
                ('1a','b',4),
                ('1a','c',5),
                ('1a','b',6),
                ('2a','b',1),
                ('2a','b',2),
                ('2a','c',3),
                ('2a','a',4),
                ('2a','c',NULL))V(id, [type], [row_number]))
SELECT YT.id,
       STUFF((SELECT '_' + sq.[type]
              FROM (SELECT T.id,
                           T.[type],
                           T.[row_number],
                           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.id, t.[type] ORDER BY t.[row_number]) AS RN
                    FROM YourTable T
                    WHERE T.id = YT.id
                      AND t.[row_number] IS NOT NULL) sq
              WHERE sq.RN = 1
              ORDER BY sq.[row_number]
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','varchar(MAX)'),1,1,'') AS new_type
FROM YourTable YT
GROUP BY YT.id;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e107e7e393aaff5f96b2b25f49f1b701)

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer using string_agg so as not to make assumptions around the number of strings to be concatenated.

```
select id,
string_agg(type, "_") within group (order by seqnum asc) as new_type
from
(
select t.id, t.type, min(t.times_purchased) as min_tp,
 row_number() over (partition by t.id order by min(t. times_purchased)) as seqnum
from table1 t
group by t.id, t.type
) as t
group by id
```